# uiimageview touches problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, touches

i am developing a card game which requires uiimageviews. i have a view based application. i have added 5imageviews in it.

each imageview has a unique card. nw the user can drag a card on top of any other card present. for this i need to know which card has been selected. how to do this?

touches enabled works in all places in my view. i want touches to be enabled only on uiimageview.

how can i activate touches to the imageviews alone present in my viewcontroller.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is in touchesBegan: method you can check which location in your view is selected using

```
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self];
```

And then do a for loop to check which imageview is selected like this

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(imageView.frame, point))
    {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint offSetPoint = [touch locationInView:myImageView];
```

Now u have defined only the myImageView object to receive the touches. Write these lines the touchesBegan or touchesEnded method as u require... Hope this helps....Dont forget to set the userInteractionEnabled property of the imageview to YES for the touches to work.

Comment: you need to chk the coordinates range for the touches to get detected only over imageview

Answer (score 1):

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
  {
     CGPoint pnt = [[touches anyObject]locationInView:self.view];
         UIImageView *imgView;
      if((pnt.x > CGRectGetMinX(imgView.frame) && pnt.x < CGRectGetMaxX(imgView.frame))&& 
            (pnt.y > CGRectGetMinY(imgView.frame) && pnt.y < CGRectGetMaxY(imgView.frame)) && 
             ChkOfferCount==TRUE)
      {
    UIAlertView *obj = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Image Touched" 
                               message:@"Selected image is this" delegate:nil  
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" 
                               otherButtonTitles:@"ok",nil];
            [obj show];
            [obj release];

      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;` and you can work with the touches methods on the imageView itself e.g. `touchesBegan:` You can work with these methods to handle the drag and drop of the cards.

Comment: thanks but no it works on whole view. i want only on imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can also create UIControl view then fill it entirely with UIImageView then simply catch touch events in UIControl.

Comment: my game requires view and small imageviews in it